# Why is the font not loading in pfpd.add_font()?

Tags: python-3.x, fpdf

I'm trying to add a font in pfpdf library to a generated pdf file but after moving a DejaVuSans.ttf to "data" directory, font cannot longer be found.

Here's a simplified code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import os

pdf = FPDF()

if os.path.isfile("./data/DejaVuSans.ttf"):
    print("oof")

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", "DejaVuSans.ttf")):
    print("foo")

print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", "DejaVuSans.ttf"))

goal_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data/DejaVuSans.ttf")
pdf.add_font("DejaVuSans", "", "DejaVuSans.ttf", uni=True)         # working if .ttf is in the same directory
#pdf.add_font("DejaVuSans", "", "./data/DejaVuSans.ttf" , uni=True) # not working
#pdf.add_font("DejaVuSans", "", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", "DejaVuSans.ttf"), uni = True) # not working
#pdf.add_font("DejaVuSans", "", r"c:\Users\ciszk\Documents\ECP\data\DejaVuSans.ttf", uni = True)  # not working
#pdf.add_font("DejaVuSans", "", os.path.abspath(goal_dir), uni = True)   # not working
pdf.set_font("DejaVuSans", size=11)

pdf.add_page()

pdf.cell(0, 10, 'Hello', 0, 1, 'C')

pdf.output('oopsie.pdf')
```

As you can see I tried multiple ways but none of them seems to be working.
That's what console returns:

> oof
>   foo
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\Users\ciszk\Documents\ECP\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 25, in 
>       pdf.output('oopsie.pdf')
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1065, in output
>       self.close()
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 246, in close
>       self._enddoc()
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1637, in _enddoc
>       self._putresources()
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1584, in _putresources
>       self._putfonts()
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1288, in _putfonts
>       ttfontstream = ttf.makeSubset(font['ttffile'], subset)
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\ttfonts.py", line 459, in makeSubset
>       self.fh = open(file ,'rb')
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DejaVuSans.ttf'

If data directory doesn't have DejaVuSans.ttf, it raises en error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\Users\ciszk\Documents\ECP\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 18, in 
>       pdf.add_font("DejaVuSans", "", os.path.abspath(goal_dir), uni = True)   # not working
>     File "C:\Users\ciszk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 469, in add_font
>       raise RuntimeError("TTF Font file not found: %s" % fname)
>   RuntimeError: TTF Font file not found: c:\Users\ciszk\Documents\ECP\data\DejaVuSans.ttf

Am I missing something very obvious? What can I do to successufully add a font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete the files with the .pkl extension in your Font directory for the front you want to use.

These files must be created when your script running because they contain all the configuration for your local font (path, prefix ...).

I think you have old font configuration and that's why it doesn't work.